Posting to LinkedIn through API call to post through Zapier
This is mainly a question about the LinkedIn versioned API (https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts).
I had hoped to use Zapier for a no-code solution, but their LinkedIn posting options are limiting to sharing a link to an article.
So I'm diving into the LinkedIn API documentation, to execute a Zapier custom LinkedIn API call.
The reason I'm sticking with Zapier is because it handles the api authorization for me and this way I don't have to struggle with access tokens.
I have 2 seperate wishes:

retrieve a list of my own personal LinkedIn posts
post a new post with text + image on my personal LinkedIn profile


For wish 1 (retrieve a list of my own personal LinkedIn posts) I'm doing

a GET request to https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts
including a header "LinkedIn-Version" with value "202408"
including a querystring parameter "author" with value urn:li:person:myID where myID is my urn number.
I have also tried replacing the colon characters to %3A, which made no difference.

The result of this request is "Failed to create a http request in LinkedIn
Raw request failed. Problem executing your request: No virtual resource found"

For wish 2 (post a new post on my personal LinkedIn profile) I tried:

a POST request to https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts
including a header "LinkedIn-Version" with value "202408"
including a stringified json as body, where myID is my urn number, like so:
{"author":"urn:li:person:myID","commentary":"This is a test post","visibility":"PUBLIC","lifecycleState":"PUBLISHED","distribution":{"feedDistribution":"MAIN_FEED","targetEntities":[],"thirdPartyDistributionChannels":[]}}

This one gives me the exact same result "No virtual resource found"

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but as most of the resources found online are for v2 of the api, I haven't been able to figure it out.
Should I be able to access this part of the API as a regular user?
When I do a GET request to https://api.linkedin.com/rest/me including the "LinkedIn-Version" header, I get a proper reponse including my profile name & headline, so I think that means the authentication works fine.
Note: I am not an app or registered as a LinkedIn developer. Though working through Zapier does obscure this a bit, I don't know how LinkedIn interprets my custom Zapier request.
I am hoping for some pointers on what I'm doing or assuming wrong here?
